# Change kubernetes config after init

Tags: kubernetes

If I init my cluster with `kubeadm` i can add some flags like `--apiserver-advertise-address`

```
$ kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 192.168.1.1
```

How can i change that config later?

Answer (score 0):

After `kubeadm init` all the flags are saved to the manifest files under `/etc/kubernetes/manifest/`.

- `etcd.yaml`
- `kube-apiserver.yaml`
- `kube-controller-manager.yaml`
- `kube-scheduler.yaml`

It depends on the scope of the flag in which of the files it occurred.
For example `--apiserver-advertise-address` is part of the API server and is stored to `kube-apiserver.yaml`. After changing the file, kubernetes will automatically restart the pod and the config will be applied.